# Who was Makarov in Edolas?

Tags: fairy-tail

When in Edolas, the story reveals that there is an alternate version of every person there, with similar yet opposite characteristics. One of the main people I could never get a confirmation on being there was Makarov. At one point, a Edolas Fairy Tail guild member says that the Guildmaster is dead, but then later Natsu believes Makarov was the evil king in Edolas. Is it either of them, or is it something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Faust has been confirmed to be Edo-Makarov by Mashima.** In the [wikia](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Faust) it is stated that Faust is the Edolas version of Makarov.

> Faust (ファウスト Fausuto) is the former King of Edolas, banished and succeeded by his disowned son, Mystogan. He is the Edolas counterpart of Makarov Dreyar.

They got this information from (the last paragraph of) the afterwords of Volume 29 by Mashima. Basically Mashima had to do cutoffs due to space or time limitations and had to remove Edolas Gajeel and Edolas Makarov('s confirmation) from the manga. Though those scenes were still added to the anime, thus making them canon as they were originally planned by Mashima himself. Both Faust and Makarov even had the same voice actor.

[Screenshot van de anime should be added here, but I can't seem to find it.]

[image]
<sub>[Source](http://estella-may.tumblr.com/post/91526336040)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the anime, when Makarov asks "How am I at Edolas?", Natsu remembers the evil king also asked the same question as Makarov asked something about "Guilds are fun", so Natsu believes he is the evil king. I think this is a little problematic thing on the story line. As 
@Dimitri mx  mentioned earlier, maybe he was dead in Edolas, or may be he has fallen to the evil side. Either way that part require some clarification from the author.

Answer (score -1):

In my point of view Makarov can't be Faust in Edolas I mean..

- They don't look alike at all
- The Fairy Tail in Edolas said the guildmaster died
- If he'd be he would be Jellal's father in Earthland as well but we know that he isn't (even though this would be quite interesting)

(Yeah this is answer is quite late I just wanted to bring this Jellal-father thing up xD)

Answer (score -1):

He is the king of Edolas but was banish as they both ask the same question is "Is Being in a guild fun?" As also Mystogan put the fairy tail symbol up as he notice the symbol and walks off as Edolas is the opposite of the person in Earth Land that why he looks so different As he is tall, And on the evil side as i heard the same voice in the dubbed as for Makarov his short and part of the ten saints WAYYYY opposite from Faust (opposite) As i think this is the Logical explanation of your question